# Counting the number of lists that are printed

Tags: python, list, count

I have a program that prints out lists like this:

```
 [1, 0, 5, 7]
 [5, 8, 9, 1]
```

I need to create code that counts how many lists are printed. So for the example above it would print 2 because there are two lists, 3 if there were three lists and so on.

Comment: Just increment a counter variable everytime you print your list(s).

Comment: You could use `enumerate()`.

Comment: If you are using unix based system you can: `./myProgram | wc -l` which will return the number of printed lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `enumerate`

```
for count,item in enumerate(input_list,1):
    # your code
print(count)
2
```

Or you can increment a `counter` while iterating :

```
count = 0
for i in input_list:
    count += 1
    # your code
print(count)
2
```